# Definir una variable global en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una clase la cual se encarga de consultar datos en la bd y luego imprmirlos mediante una impresora Zebra Bluetooth, mantengo distintos procesos dentro de esta tarea, necesito asignar un mensaje el cual retorne la respuesta correspondiente a cada proceso. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

public class PruebaBlouetooth {

```
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
private String urlip = "http://200.113.127.85:8085/";
private ArrayList<Muestra> listaMuestra;
private Muestra m;
private String mensaje;


public String consultarMuestras(String proyecto,final String macAddres) {
    //Consular muestras

    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url6 = urlip + "ListarMuestras?PROJECT=" + proyecto;
    cliente.get(url6, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            //Deja el json en una variable
            String sd = new String(responseBody);
            listaMuestra = new ArrayList<Muestra>();
            //Se recorre el json y setea los valores en la lista
            try {//Conexion con la impresora y datos a imprimir
                 mensaje = "Impreso correctamente";
                }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 mensaje = "error de conexion con impresora";
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            mensaje = "Fallo la conexion con el servidor";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
            return false;
        }


    });
    return mensaje;
}
```

Luego de procesar todo obtengo el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
private class TareaImprimir extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute(){
        cargando2.setCancelable(false);
        cargando2.setTitle("Conectando con impresora");
        cargando2.setMessage("Por favor, espere");
        cargando2.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        PruebaBlouetooth p = new PruebaBlouetooth();
        mensaje = p.consultarMuestras(proyecto,macAddres);
        SystemClock.sleep(2500);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        cargando2.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(ListadoProyectos.this, "Ejecutado "+mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

El mensaje que obtengo es un Null, ya que no puede obtener la variable mensaje dentro de los procesos. 
Por favor agradecería mucho su ayuda y espero que se entienda el problema.
Saludos.

Comment: El problema es que tu función consultarMuestras ejecuta el get asincrono, y retorna inmediatamente antes de que se ejecute el onSuccess, que se ejecuta cuando termina el get, tarde lo que tarde. Tienes un problema de diseño. De alguna manera en la tarea tienes que esperar a que termine el onSuccess antes de acceder a la variable message. Tienes ayuda [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229989/how-to-get-asynchttpclient-onsucces-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exacto como dice SuperG280, cuando intentas retornar de un metodo asyncrono un valor, este valor siempre va a ser null, por que antes de que termine de ir al servidor a buscar la lista , el codigo ya paso por `return mensaje;`

Lo que deberias hacer es una interfaz que te avise cuando el metodo `onSuccess()` termino, de esta forma podes manejar mejor el flujo

```
 interface CallbackMuestras{
     void onSuccess(String mensaje);
     void onFailure(String errorMsg);
    }
```

Luego en el código del fetch

```
public consultarMuestras(String proyecto,final String macAddres,CallbackMuestras callback) {
    //Consular muestras

    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url6 = urlip + "ListarMuestras?PROJECT=" + proyecto;
    cliente.get(url6, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            //Deja el json en una variable
            String sd = new String(responseBody);
            listaMuestra = new ArrayList<Muestra>();
            //Se recorre el json y setea los valores en la lista
            try {//Conexion con la impresora y datos a imprimir
                 mensaje = "Impreso correctamente";
                 callback.onSuccess(mensaje);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 mensaje = "error de conexion con impresora";
                 callback.onFailure(mensaje);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            mensaje = "Fallo la conexion con el servidor";
            callback.onFailure(mensaje);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
            return false;
        }


    });
}
```

Por ultimo llamas al metodo y aguardas el valor

```
consultarMuestras("proyecto","mac address",new CallbackMuestras() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String mensaje) {
           //Hace lo que quieras cuando tengas el mensaje
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String errorMsg) {
           //Hace lo que quieras cuando hay un error
        }
    });
}
```