# FirebaseAuth no termina de iniciar sesion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-auth

El problema es que al momento de cambiar la contrasenia de una cuenta de FirebaseAuth, necesito volver a iniciar sesion, para lo cual pido la contrasenia al usuario, el problema es que tengo un metodo que hace eso, el cual inicia sesion de nuevo, y tengo un bucle para esperar a que termine de iniciar sesion, el funcionamiento del bucle consiste basicamente en esperar el cambio de una variable booleana a true, lo cual sucede cuando se recarga la sesion, pero esto nunca pasa, me pasa lo mismo con FirebaseDatabase, pienso que el bucle no deja que FirebaseAuth ni FirebaseDatabase se ejecuten, hay alguna forma de esperar a que termine de ejecutarse el inicio de sesion,y no tener este problema?

Codigo:

---

```
final boolean[] resultado=new boolean[]{false};
final boolean[] ready = {false};
if(userActual.getEmail()==null){
    return false;
}
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userActual.getEmail(),
             contraCuenta.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        resultado[0]=true;
                    }else{
                        resultado[0]=false;
                        if(task.getException()!=null){
                            Mensajes.showToast_Center_InActivity(activity,
                                    task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }
                    }
                    ready[0]=true;
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
while (true){
    if(ready[0]){
        break;
    }
}
return resultado[0];
```

Comment: no hace falta que lo metas a un thread ni que le pongas un bucle infinito. el signInWithEmailAndPassword trabaja de forma asincronica. Simplemente llama al metodo que necesites dentro del onComplete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice Erick, no hace falta que lo pongas en otro Thread ya que Firebase se va a encargar de colgar a otro hilo la operacion asyncrona. Tampoco hace falta por el ejemplo que muestras de almacenar el boolean en un array, simplemente lo podes usar con **final boolean ready = false;**

Al ser una operacion asyncrona, cada vez que haces

```
return resultado[0];
```

Vas a retornar siempre **false**, ya que aun no termino el `onComplete` del metodo `signInWithEmailAndPassword` de resolverse.

Hay dos formas de resolver este problema

una es poniendo luego de iniciar sesion la logica que usas con la variable boolean ahi mismo

```
 if(task.isSuccessful()){ 
   //Logica de variable boolean en true
 }
```

Y la otra es usar una interfaz para saber cuando este task termino para retornar un valor booleano **true** o **false**

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como usar interfaces

[Definir una variable global en android studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303238/definir-una-variable-global-en-android-studio/303317#303317)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que dices me ayudo, hay alguna manera  de esperar a que termine de ejecutarse?, ya que de otra forma, como a ese metodo lo llamo desde muchas partes, donde va la 'Logica de variable boolean en true' inicio un Thread que lo paso como parametron al metodo, pero es poco reusable de esta manera

Comment: Codigo que uso actualmente:                                                                       public static void refrescarToken(final Thread onFinished) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                
                    onFinished.start();
                  
            }
        });
    }